# In SQL Server, if I have a UNIQUE constraint on multiple fields, do I need an index on one of those fields?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a UNIQUE constraint on multiple fields, created like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQ__mytable UNIQUE (field1, field2, field3);
```

The fields have the following types:

```
field1: bigint
field2: int
field3: varchar(16)
```

Now I think I'll do a lot of JOINS on `field1` alone. Do I also need to have a specific index on `field1` to have the best performance?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

When creating a unique constraint in SQL Server, the engine will also create a unique index on the fields specified in the constraint (maintaining the same order). So if for example you have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(A INT NOT NULL, B NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, C INT NOT NULL, D CHAR(4) NULL);
```

and you create a unique constraint like that:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQ_foo_A_B_C UNIQUE (A,B,C);
```

Then you get a unique constraint AND a unique index which look like that:

[image]

Which will perfectly satisfy the joins you do in the A column (in your case field1).

Comment: Interesting! I did not know that.  Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 3):

If `field1` is "narrow" (e.g. `int`, `tinyint`, etc) and fields 2 and 3 are wide (such that you're stretching the limits of 900 bytes per index key) it may make sense to create a "narrow" index on just `field1`. This index could benefit from being able to store a lot more index keys per page.

As [S Karras has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52761723/15498), there's already *an* index here which can be used to satisfy predicates based on `field1`.

So if you want to try this, add the index and try a few common queries to see if it's *used* or not.

Comment: `field1: bigint`, `field2: int`, `field3: varchar(16)` do you think an extra index is worth to try?

Comment: @baxeico - probably not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

S.Krras is right, you'll get the index automatically.  I have always just directly made the index instead.  What you may want to consider is using a `unique covering index`.  Something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [your_index_name] ON [dbo].[your_table_name]
(
    [field1] ASC,
    [field2] ASC,
    [field3] ASC
)
```

That will give you the benefits of the constraint *and* performance gain if you are joining on `field1` and returning data from the other fields.  There is quite a bit of art in SQL to trying things for performance tuning.  It's always a good idea to look at your execution plan to see what really needs to be done.

Some interesting reading for you, using a `unique constraint` vs `unique index`

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4270/difference-between-sql-server-unique-indexes-and-unique-constraints/

Seems that either is fine, just depends on what you really want to do.